# Receiving error while integrating DocuSign with Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

[Error Messages:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tZKt.png) When I am trying to connect DocuSign with salesforce, I am getting error "Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element turnTLSv11Off"

1. Install DocuSign for Salesforce from App Exchange
2. Go to DocuSign Admin tab
3. Connect DocuSign demo account. It will get connected successfully.
4. Connect DocuSign with Salesforce . Enter Salesforce username and credentials
   Error messages : Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element turnTLSv11Off

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that is being investigated. The current workaround is to configure SF Admin credentials in Connect (Log in to the DocuSign Web Console > Settings > Connect > Salesforce > Reconfigure login). As the previous step is completed, that'll get things linked from both sides.